# What are the most notable effects of adding android:targetSdkVersion="10" and why does it control the presence of "Menu" button on Android 3.1 tablet?

Tags: android

I had some kind of problem with my application a long time ago, and the suggested solution was to add `android:targetSdkVersion="10"` to the manifest. It did the trick, so this line stayed. Now I want to either remove it or target one of the latest Android APIs, but I can't recall what was that problem that I've fixed by targeting API level 10, so if I break it I wouldn't know. Any suggestions?

I'm using Android 3.1 SDK (API level 12), and `android:minSdkVersion` is and always have been 12.

**Upd.** Found one effect of `targetSdkVersion="10"`: if it's set to anything > 10 or not set at all my app does not have the "Menu" button (or however it's called) on Android 3.1 tablet. I'm absolutely sure that this was not the case some time ago and this is not the answer I'm looking for.
I do need that button, though. Is `android:targetSdkVersion` supposed to have this effect (again, this wasn't the case like 9 months ago)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> android:minSdkVersion is and always have been 12.

Having `android:targetSdkVersion` set to a lower value than `android:minSdkVersion` is very odd.

> Found one effect of targetSdkVersion="10": if it's set to anything > 10 or not set at all my app does not have the "Menu" button (or however it's called) on Android 3.1 tablet.

Correct. It also controls your default theme (`Theme.Holo` and variants for the holographic widget set).

> I'm absolutely sure that this was not the case some time ago

This behavior has been the case for nearly two years, since the advent of Android 3.0 in February 2010. However, [the story got a bit more complicated with the release of Android 4.0](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html).

> I do need that button

Add an action bar or do not use an options menu. The legacy menu affordance [is not available as you raise your `android:targetSdkVersion`](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html).

> Is android:targetSdkVersion supposed to have this effect

Yes.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer to a poorly stated question.